# bot discord if someone click reaction change message and delete reaction discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

hello to everybody i have a problem i try to learn bot with python for discord.
i try to make a bot can modify a message and sign in the message all the people put a reaction and remove the people who put another reaction

I dont understand how i can

i put this code:

i dont know how i  can make remove automatic the reaction and change the variable with the name of the people thanks for

```html
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()
var1 = "placeholder"
var2 = "placeholder"


@client.event


async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        #titolo= input('Inserisci un titolo') ricorda di cambiare title sotto
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title='Staff Disponibile', description="Controlla chi dello staff è in servizio per aiutarti o per farti la whitelist", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var1 , value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var2 , value="hi2", inline=False)
        mess = await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
        await mess.add_reaction('✅')
        await mess.add_reaction('❌')
        #await message.clear_reaction("✅")





client.run (my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have another listener for reaction add as when the command gets run, it gets ran once and cannot listen for reaction adds.
Anyways the actual code is here:

```py
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()
var1 = "placeholder"
var2 = "placeholder"


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title='Staff Disponibile', description="Controlla chi dello staff è in servizio per aiutarti o per farti la whitelist", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var1 , value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var2 , value="hi2", inline=False)
        mess = await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
        await mess.add_reaction('✅')
        await mess.add_reaction('❌')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    #idk if this part is needed. Just put it to make sure the message and channel are fetched.
    if user.id == client.user.id:
      return;
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(reaction.message.channel.id) # Making sure you have the channel in cache
    message = await channel.fetch_message(reaction.message.id)
    await reaction.remove(user) #reaction removes everytime any one clicked
    if reaction.emoji == "✅":
        var1 = user.display_name #or whatever the variable you need to replace.
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title='Staff Disponibile', description="Controlla chi dello staff è in servizio per aiutarti o per farti la whitelist", color=0x00ff00)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var1 , value="hi", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name=var2 , value="hi2", inline=False)
        await message.edit(embed=embedVar)

client.run (my_secret)
```

This should work as I tested it.
If it doesn't post a comment and I will try my best to help you!

Tip: Press the grey check mark beside this answer to accept it, and support me!